# How come I did not have to specify the submodules when importing?

Tags: python, import, sqlalchemy

Take a look:

```
In [1]: from sqlalchemy import select
In [2]: select
Out[3]: <function sqlalchemy.expression.select>
```

I don't understand how the above code can work. You should always specify the complete path right? Like this:

```
In [1]: from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select
In [2]: select
Out[2]: <function sqlalchemy.expression.select>
```

Another question: `sqlalchemy` is telling me that the path is `sqlalchemy.expression.select` but how about the "sql" part.

Take a look:

```
In [1]:from sqlalchemy.expression import select
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     from sqlalchemy.expression import select
ImportError: No module named 'sqlalchemy.expression'
```

How come Python ignores the sql part here: `sqlalchemy.expression.select` and when I try to use his own path it doesn't work.

Please advise

Comment: "from sqlalchemy import select" works because sqlalchemy is a python package. When trying to import, Python reads it from python-default-installed-packages folder. You can specify the full path too.. but there's no need of it.

Comment: You should definitely read the sections `import `and packages concepts [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=packages#packages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in the sqlalchemy's [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/__init__.py), it imports select from .sql. How does it import from .sql when it is under expression? If you also look at sqlalchemy.sql's [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/__init__.py), it imports from select from .expression already. Therefore, there is no need to provide full path `from sqlalchemy.sql.expression` when trying to `import select`. You could just `from sqlalchemy import select`.
As mentioned, because `sqlalchemy` already imports from `select` in it's `__init__.py`, the sql part is ignored.